# Android MVVM retrofit2 model not updating

Tags: android, retrofit2, android-mvvm

Trying to call my API using retrofit and update the model. It initializes correctly and is able to pull the data but when I trigger it manually by pressing the update button the onChange QuestionResponse model is null. It seems almost like a race condition as when debugging it will hit the onChange before the onResponse is called. I've tried changing from setValue to postvalue etc.

Activity

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(BasicViewModel.class);
    mViewModel.getQuestions().observe(this, new Observer<QuestionResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(QuestionResponse response) {
            QuestionResponse temp = mViewModel.getQuestions().getValue();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Questions Updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    updateButton = findViewById(R.id.updateButton);
    updateButton .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            update();
        }
    });
}

private void update(){
    mViewModel.updateQuestions();
}
```

View Model

```
private Repository repository;
private Application application;
private MutableLiveData<QuestionResponse> questionMutableLiveData;

public BasicViewModel(Application application){
    super(application);
    this.application = application;
    repository = new Repository();
    questionMutableLiveData = repository.getQuotes();
}

public void updateQuestions(){
    questionMutableLiveData.setValue(repository.getQuotes().getValue());
}

public LiveData<QuestionResponse> getQuestions(){
    if(questionMutableLiveData == null){
        System.out.println("Something Is Wrong");
    }
    return questionMutableLiveData;
}
```

Retrofit Service

```
public class Repository {
    MutableLiveData<QuestionResponse> questionData;
    ApiService apiService;

    public QuoteMRepository(){
        apiService = RetrofitSingleton.getRetrofitInstance().create(ApiService.class);
    }

    public MutableLiveData<QuestionResponse> getQuotes(){
        Call<QuestionResponse> call = apiService.getQuestions();

        //Old version of doing it 
        //MutableLiveData<QuestionResponse> questionData = new MutableLiveData<>();

        //New version, seems to be working but triggering twice 
        if(questionData == null) {
            questionData = new MutableLiveData<>();
        }    

        call.enqueue(new Callback<QuestionResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<QuestionResponse> call, Response<QuestionResponse> response) {
                if(response.isSuccessful()){
                    QuestionResponse reply = response.body();
                    questionData.setValue(reply);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<QuestionResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                System.out.println("Failure");
            }
        });

        return questionData;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are returning an empty `LiveData` object and later updating it with the repository response, so your observer triggers twice, once for `null`, once for the response.

```
public MutableLiveData<QuestionResponse> getQuotes(){
    Call<QuestionResponse> call = apiService.getQuestions();
    MutableLiveData<QuestionResponse> questionData = new MutableLiveData<>();

    call.enqueue(new Callback<QuestionResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<QuestionResponse> call, Response<QuestionResponse> response) {
            if(response.isSuccessful()){
                QuestionResponse reply = response.body();
                questionData.setValue(reply);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<QuestionResponse> call, Throwable t) {
            System.out.println("Failure");
        }
    });

    // THIS RETURNS AN EMPTY OBJECT AND LATER UPDATES
    return questionData;
}
```

You could filter by `null` on your observer, or use a `SwitchMap` for your `LiveData` and return a wrapper that indicates loading, for instance.

Comment: Why would it not happen when the ViewModel was created and only when updateQuestions is called? I've looked at a number of examples and I don't think they are using any type of filtering in the observer. 
https://medium.com/@amtechnovation/android-architecture-component-mvvm-part-1-a2e7cff07a76 as an example. A simple solution would be to move my api call into my viewmodel but that kinda breaks the pattern.

Comment: Because your value is initially null, so assigning null again does not trigger the observer.

Comment: Hmm not sure I fully understand what you were saying to do but your comment gave me an idea. I am returning a new mutable LiveData every time as you said that my main activity is not listening too. I edited code my question to show the change in the Repository. It seems to work though may be triggering twice still.

Comment: Your updated code shouldn't trigger twice. You could also initialize the LiveData object on declaration.

Comment: It's definitely triggering twice but by changing questionMutableLiveData.setValue(repository.getQuotes().getValue()); to just repository.getQuotes().getValue() seems to fix it

Answer (score 0):

Believe I solved this one. First problem was I was always creating and returning a new mutable-list in my repository. This new list wasn't being observed but still being assigned a value. The reason onChange observable was still being triggered in the main activity is because in the ViewModel questionMutableLiveData.setValue(repository.getQuotes().getValue()) was actually changing the data but with a null value of the newly created mutable-list.

If there's any feedback if this is correct or a better way to organize the repository / viewmodel I would love to hear it!

Activity

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(BasicViewModel.class);
    mViewModel.getQuestions().observe(this, new Observer<QuestionResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(QuestionResponse response) {
            QuestionResponse temp = mViewModel.getQuestions().getValue();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Questions Updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    updateButton = findViewById(R.id.updateButton);
    updateButton .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            update();
        }
    });
}

private void update(){
    mViewModel.updateQuestions();
}
```

View Model

```
private Repository repository;
private Application application;
private MutableLiveData<QuestionResponse> questionMutableLiveData;

public BasicViewModel(Application application){
    super(application);
    this.application = application;
    repository = new Repository();
    questionMutableLiveData = repository.getQuotes();
}

public void updateQuestions(){
    repository.getQuotes().getValue();
}

public LiveData<QuestionResponse> getQuestions(){
    if(questionMutableLiveData == null){
        System.out.println("Something Is Wrong");
    }
    return questionMutableLiveData;
}
```

Retrofit Service

```
public class Repository {
    MutableLiveData<QuestionResponse> questionData;
    ApiService apiService;

    public QuoteMRepository(){
        apiService = RetrofitSingleton.getRetrofitInstance().create(ApiService.class);
    }

    public MutableLiveData<QuestionResponse> getQuotes(){
        Call<QuestionResponse> call = apiService.getQuestions();

        if(questionData == null) {
            questionData = new MutableLiveData<>();
        }    

        call.enqueue(new Callback<QuestionResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<QuestionResponse> call, Response<QuestionResponse> response) {
                if(response.isSuccessful()){
                    QuestionResponse reply = response.body();
                    questionData.setValue(reply);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<QuestionResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                System.out.println("Failure");
            }
        });

        return questionData;
    }
}
```